QField does not execute a PostGIS trigger
I have a project in PostgreSQL/PostGIS. Simplifying, there are two tables, "raccolta_dati" with fields "dati_id" and "num_accessione", and "foto_campo" with the field "dati_raccolta_id" and "num_accessione". The two tables have a one-to-many relationship established in QGIS/QField "dati_id" - "dati_raccolta_id". On the database side, I've set up a trigger to set the "num_accessione" of the "foto_campo" table equal to the value of "num_accessione" in the "raccolta_dati" table on the basis of the one-to-many relationship. Everything works fine with both insert and update, both on the database side and in the QGIS project.
However, when I synchronize the QField project, everything gets filled in correctly except for the "num_accessione" field in the "foto_campo" table which remains empty. It seems like the synchronization process isn't activating the trigger. However, I have other active triggers of a spatial type (for example, in the "raccolta_dati" table, the fields "comune", "provincia", and "regione" are automatically filled based on spatial relationships with the administrative boundaries layer present in the database) that are executed perfectly even through synchronization.
Here the code of the trigger:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fill_num_accessione()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $fill_num_accessione$
  
BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP='INSERT') THEN
  UPDATE foto_campo as f
    SET num_accessione = d.num_accessione
    FROM dati_raccolta as d
    WHERE d.dati_id = f.dati_raccolta_id;
  ELSIF(TG_OP='UPDATE') THEN
  UPDATE foto_campo as f
    SET num_accessione = d.num_accessione
    FROM dati_raccolta as d
    WHERE d.dati_id = f.dati_raccolta_id;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;

$fill_num_accessione$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER fill_num_accessione_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON foto_campo
  FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE fill_num_accessione();

CREATE TRIGGER fill_num_accessione_update
  AFTER UPDATE ON foto_campo
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (OLD.dati_raccolta_id IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.dati_raccolta_id)
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE fill_num_accessione();


Are you using the same user/authentication when making changes to the table via QGIS?

Thanks to your input, I had the insight that the issue might be related to some permissions, and indeed, the user entering the data didn't have the permissions on the trigger.

Awesome, glad it worked out!
